# Let's Encrypt Python Client Fails (Certbot-Auto)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lets-encrypt, certbot

I see this error message below. The client previously worked on exactly the same environment. I don't understand anything from Python.

How can I fix this? My current certificate expires in a couple of hours.

```
// a lot of other stuff updated ...
Setting up gcc (4:6.3.0-4) ...
Setting up python-virtualenv (15.1.0+ds-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-5) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20161130) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Creating virtual environment...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 662, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 970, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 861, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (virtualenv 15.0.3 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('virtualenv==15.1.0'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2991, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2977, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 664, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 677, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 856, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'virtualenv==15.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Comment: Looks like you found virtualenv 15.0.3 but require 15.1.0... did the repos change?

Comment: What do you mean with repo? @AIG

Comment: I don't know the cause of this, you could try uninstalling and reinstalling virtualenv with pip: `pip uninstall virtualenv` / `pip install virtualenv==15.1.0`

Comment: Whatever script you are running is failing at `Creating virtual environment...` with the error mentioned above. Feels like there was a change (like what @chrki mentioned) there. I'd start chasing it from there... did an install fail (previously)? Did someone update this? etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. However, there is no pip installed... Do I have to install this? @chrki

Comment: @nxrd You could try `python -m pip install virtualenv==15.1.0` (might work if pip is installed but not in your PATH, otherwise you have to install it: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` - **or** it might actually be called `pip3` since you are using Python3

Comment: @chrki Okay I installed python3-pip now. However, I couldn't uninstall it: "Not uninstalling virtualenv at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr". Installing the new version seems to work, even though it says the same (not uninstalling blabla), but finishes with "Successfully installed virtualenv-15.1.0"

Comment: @chrki Thanks so much, it worked. :-)

Answer (score -1):

The `python-virtualenv` version from your distribution or installation is older than what's required by Certbot-Auto.

Install or upgrade to a compatible `virtualenv` version for Python 3 via

```
pip3 install virtualenv>=15.1.0
```